# Angular how to add 2 values?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am adding 2 values but not getting the expected result.

For example `1 + 1 = 2` but i am getting `11`

My code

```
this.newpoint = this.data.point + 1;
console.log(this.newpoint);
```

this.data.point value is 0 but its in string maybe this is the problem ?

Comment: So let's say `this.data.point` is type `string` how would YOU make that a number? Forget angular for a moment, how would you do it with JavaScript? What have you tried to solve this issue?

Comment: I think you are answering your own question @UmaiZ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```js
this.newpoint = parseInt(this.data.point) + 1;
console.log(this.newpoint);
```

Hope this help you

Comment: a quick way is prefix '+' a value: this.newpoint=+this.data.point+1

Answer (score 1):

```
this.newpoint = parseInt(this.data.point, 10) + 1;
```

Don't know how you're getting `'11'` and not `'01'` though.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var num = 1;
var newpoint = Number(num) + 1;
alert(newpoint);
```

TRY THIS